# All-natural or All-Natural?

Tags: hyphens, capitalization

If I am using a word like all-natural in a title or logo, would it be All-natural or All-Natural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there are some rules governing titles, titles are often an expression of art or marketing more than grammar.  Consequently, [poetic license](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/poetic-licence) is common (meaning the rules of grammar are bent or broken to meet the artistic or marketing needs of the title).  That's a lengthy way of saying this is often an issue of personal choice.

However, the common rules are:

- If in a title you capitlize any word in a hyphenated compound-word, all words in the hyphenated compound word should be capitalized.
- Titles frequently use capitalized words for all but connecting words (of, and, or, in, etc.).

So, my recommendation is to use All-Natural in a title.

*To give you an example of the poetic license nature of titles: Most Stack Exchange sites expect question titles to use sentence-case, not title-case.  Meaning the "title" has its first letter capitalized, but nothing else.*